# mongodb query slow in different version and env

Tags: mongodb

I have two env mongodbs,
the difference between them is:
test mongodb version: 3.2.20 , prod mongodb version : 4.0.18
and test env query plan first stage is Limit , however the other is Sort.

in my test env, it's very quick and totalDocsExamined == limit

they both hit the index:
{
"v" : 1,
"key" : {
"appIds" : 1,
"ctime" : -1,
"background" : 1
},
"name" : "appIds_1_ctime_-1_background_1",
"ns" : "newsmine.newstoapp"
}

query: db.newstoapp.find({"appIds":{"$in":[999]}}).sort({"ctime":-1}).limit(10).explain('executionStats')

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "newsmine.newstoapp",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "appIds" : {
                                "$in" : [
                                        999
                                ]
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "LIMIT",
                        "limitAmount" : 10,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "appIds" : 1,
                                                "ctime" : -1,
                                                "background" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "appIds_1_ctime_-1_background_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "appIds" : [
                                                        "[999.0, 999.0]"
                                                ],
                                                "ctime" : [
                                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                ],
                                                "background" : [
                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 10,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 10,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 10,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "LIMIT",
                        "nReturned" : 10,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 11,
                        "advanced" : 10,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "limitAmount" : 10,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "nReturned" : 10,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 10,
                                "advanced" : 10,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 0,
                                "restoreState" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "docsExamined" : 10,
                                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "nReturned" : 10,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                        "works" : 10,
                                        "advanced" : 10,
                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 0,
                                        "restoreState" : 0,
                                        "isEOF" : 0,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "appIds" : 1,
                                                "ctime" : -1,
                                                "background" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "appIds_1_ctime_-1_background_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "appIds" : [
                                                        "[999.0, 999.0]"
                                                ],
                                                "ctime" : [
                                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                ],
                                                "background" : [
                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "keysExamined" : 10,
                                        "dupsTested" : 10,
                                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "",
                "port" : ,
                "version" : "3.2.20",
                "gitVersion" : "a7a144f40b70bfe290906eb33ff2714933544af8"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

in my prod env, it's getting slow query
query: datamongo:PRIMARY> db.newstoapp.find({"appIds":{"$in":[1460]}}).sort({"ctime":-1}).limit(10).explain('executionStats')

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "newsmine.newstoapp",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "appIds" : {
                                "$eq" : 1460
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "SORT",
                        "sortPattern" : {
                                "ctime" : -1
                        },
                        "limitAmount" : 10,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "appIds" : 1,
                                                        "ctime" : -1,
                                                        "background" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "appIds_1_ctime_-1_background_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "appIds" : [
                                                                "[1460.0, 1460.0]"
                                                        ],
                                                        "ctime" : [
                                                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                        ],
                                                        "background" : [
                                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "ctime" : -1
                                },
                                "limitAmount" : 10,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "appIds" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "appIds_1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "appIds" : [
                                                                        "[1460.0, 1460.0]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                                "limitAmount" : 10,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "filter" : {
                                                "appIds" : {
                                                        "$eq" : 1460
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "ctime" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "ctime_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                "direction" : "backward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "ctime" : [
                                                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 10,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 40,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 405,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 405,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "SORT",
                        "nReturned" : 10,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3,
                        "works" : 418,
                        "advanced" : 10,
                        "needTime" : 407,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 9,
                        "restoreState" : 9,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "sortPattern" : {
                                "ctime" : -1
                        },
                        "memUsage" : 8471,
                        "memLimit" : 33554432,
                        "limitAmount" : 10,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                "nReturned" : 405,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3,
                                "works" : 407,
                                "advanced" : 405,
                                "needTime" : 1,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 9,
                                "restoreState" : 9,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "nReturned" : 405,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3,
                                        "works" : 406,
                                        "advanced" : 405,
                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 9,
                                        "restoreState" : 9,
                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "docsExamined" : 405,
                                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "nReturned" : 405,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1,
                                                "works" : 406,
                                                "advanced" : 405,
                                                "needTime" : 0,
                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                "saveState" : 9,
                                                "restoreState" : 9,
                                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "appIds" : 1,
                                                        "ctime" : -1,
                                                        "background" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "appIds_1_ctime_-1_background_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "appIds" : [
                                                                "[1460.0, 1460.0]"
                                                        ],
                                                        "ctime" : [
                                                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                        ],
                                                        "background" : [
                                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                        ]
                                                },
                                                "keysExamined" : 405,
                                                "seeks" : 1,
                                                "dupsTested" : 405,
                                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "",
                "port" : ,
                "version" : "4.0.18",
                "gitVersion" : "6883bdfb8b8cff32176b1fd176df04da9165fd67"
        },
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1629988625, 146),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1629988625, 146),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
```

i followed Joe, changed my index, ctime before appIds.
but it does not work very well. there still be slow log for my new sql. it's hard to find out why it is slow

```
2021-10-19T22:38:16.918+0800 I COMMAND  [conn2434281164] command newsmine.newstoapp command: find { find: "newstoapp", filter: { appIds: { $elemMatch: { $in: [ 2433 ] } }, ctime: { $gte: 0 } }, sort: { ctime: -1 }, hint: { ctime: -1, appIds: 1 }, skip: 0, limit: 50, batchSize: 50, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "newsmine" } planSummary: IXSCAN { ctime: -1, appIds: 1 } keysExamined:1471582 docsExamined:50 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:11496 nreturned:50 reslen:34043 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 11497 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 11497 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 11497 } } } storage:{ data: { bytesRead: 44958, timeReadingMicros: 618 } } protocol:op_query 7038ms
```

Comment: Which of those fields contains an array?

Comment: only appIds contains array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the slowness is that MongoDB 4.0.18 hash a blocking sort stage, so *all* matching documents must be found, retrieved,  and sorted in memory before returning the requested batch.

In prior versions of MongoDB it was found that under certain conditions using a multi-key index to support a sort would provide incorrect result.
I never fully understood these conditions or why the results were incorrect, so if you are able to find those details, please edit or comment.

Prior to MongoDB 3.4 the index metadata contained a boolean value to indicate whether or not the index was multi-key (indexed a field that contained an array for at least one document).

MongoDB 3.4 introduced a new index version that also keeps track of which fields in the index are multi-key.

MongoDB 3.6 introduced a [change to sorting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#sorting) to avoid the situations where results would be incorrect.  This is why your query has a sort stage and is taking longer.

There are a couple things you could try to get back to the previous behavior without a blocking sort:

- Drop and rebuild the index.
  The existing index is version 1, which does not track multi-key paths.  When rebuilding, the index should be created at version 2, which does track these, and may permit the query executor to use the index for sorting.
- Create a new index with `ctime` before `appIds`.
  A multi-key index has an entry in the index for each value in the indexed array. This may cause the query planner to assume it will disrupt sorting on a following key.
  An index on `{ctime:-1, appIds:1, background:1}` would place the sort key ahead of the multi-key field, and while this may require reading more of the *index*, it may also permit the query executor to use the index for sorting.

Comment: I Create a new index with ctime before appIds.  but it dose not work very well.  I edit my question again for continues help... thank you so much

Comment: I just noticed `"isMultiKey" : true,` in the explain.  It was discovered that using a version 1 multikey index for sorting occasionally produced incorrect results.  Rebuild that index on MongoDB 4.0 so that it becomes version 2, and it might be able to support the sort.